# How can I tell if my activity was started by a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an alarm clock application I am making. I have one activity where the user sets the time for the alarm. This registers a broadcast receiver class I have made to receive a broadcast at the time of the alarm, using `AlarmManager`. I then start a new activity in the receivers `onReceive()`. When this second activity starts, the alarm clock sound is played in `onStart()`. How can I tell if my activity has been started by a receiver or if the user is just multitasking with the application? I don't want my sound to play when the user silences the alarm, presses the home button, and then renters the app (while still on the sound playing activity).

Comment: Couldn't you put an Extra on the Intent you send to `onReceive()` method?

Comment: How about putting an extra in the intent I create in the receiver's onReceive() for starting activity #2? Then i could play the sound if the intent had an extra, or will that extra still be there next time someone starts that activity #2 again?

Comment: I don't think it will still be there. Try that approach.

Comment: The intent, with it's extras, are still there upon backgrounding and bringing back the app :(

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem? You are trying to launch an activity from receiver or another activity, and you want to know that if activity has been started from receiver. Am I correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just send an extra via the intent you use in your `onReceive()` method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("playSound", true);
```

in your "sound playing" activity, **you have to play the sound in `onCreate()`**:

```
boolean playSound = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("playSound", false);
```

This will return false if the intent-extra "playSound" does not exist or is set to false, true if it is set to true.

---

`onCreate()` is only called once (when the activity starts), while `onStart()` gets called everytime a user reenters your activity (i.e. through recent apps). You can see this in the lifecycle:
[image: android activity lifecycle]

(diagram [source](http://web.archive.org/web/20140218132043/http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html))

Where *Paused* is called when something draws over you activity (e.g. low battery dialog), *Stopped* is called if you "exit" your app (e.g. through the home-button).

Answer (score 2):

Start an activity or a service, etc., based on a received broadcast then you need a standalone broadcast receiver and you put that in your android manifest file. If you want your activity itself to respond to broadcasts then you create an instance of a broadcast receiver in your activity and register it there.

```
public class BRActivity extends Activity {
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ..................
        ..................
    }
};

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);

    this.registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver , filter);
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    this.unregisterReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver );
}
```

}

So, this way the receiver is instantiated when the class is created (could also do in onCreate). Then in the onResume/onPause I handle registering and unregistering the receiver. Then in the reciever's onReceive method I do whatever is necessary to make the activity react the way I want to when it receives the broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

1. For each alarm user sets, you put an boolean flag in sharedpreference to true. E.g. you have three alarms then in sharedpreference you will have 3 flags.
2. Now suppose a alarm broadcast is received for alarm1 and activity2 is started.
3. Now in activity2 first thing you check is whether the flag for alarm1 which you set in sharedpreference is true or false, if true play sound.
4. When user silences the alarm or press home button then you can mark this flag to false, so next time if user starts activity from background, flag in sharedpreference will be false and sound will not be played.

Same thing you can achieve using sqlite db, by setting flags in sqlite db table instead of sharedpreference.

Answer (score 0):

For the intent used to launch the sound playing activity use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS flag. So if the user moves out of the activity, it cannot be resumed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SoundActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

or in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="SoundActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
</activity>
```

Comment: This is a hack though, interfering with the UI just in order to avoid a technical consequence that can just be fixed with an extra as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Yes. But provided the use case as an alarm clock, generally the alarm activity, or SoundActivity is no more required once the user dismisses the alarm. For snooze, one can very well have another alarm with a fixed short interval. And other activities of the app will still show up in recents.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of solutions:

(1) one approach is to use a Singleton Class which can be shared across activity.
In this approach set a boolean flag of Singleton class in BroadcastReceiver and then check that flag in the activity (which is fired from your BroadcastReceiver) where you play sound. Please reset the flag if it is set. This solution assumes that the Broadcast receiver is part of your Android App package.

(2)
Alternatively, you can also use Intet.putExtra ("Key", Value) method when you start an activity from BroadcastReceiver. You can check this key in the Activity you started from BroadcastReceiver to know who started this activity.

So this will take care of detecting where you come from.

If you are simply trying to set single (one-shot ) alarm then creating another activity for playing the sound is OK. If you set repeat alarm ( alarm plays at a multiple interval), I am not sure how your application will behave.

I prefer to play the sound in the Broadcast receiver itself (registered as remote receiver in manifest) for a specified duration for a given alarm ( like 30 sec of sound or you can ask user to configure it). 
So this way you can use the same BroadcastReceiver for playing sound for single-shot & multi-repeat alarm.
I will use the same PendingIntent for setting both Single-shot and multi-repeat alarm.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to find if app is started via broadcast receiver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

    String AlarmTriggerString = (String)intent.getSerializableExtra("AlarmTrigger");
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.prasath.viki.bot","com.prasath.viki.bot.MainActivity");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra("FromBroacastReceiver",true);
    i.putExtra("AlarmTrigger",AlarmTriggerString);
    context.startActivity(i);

    }
}


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boolean FromReceiver = (boolean)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("FromBroacastReceiver");
    String AlarmTriggerString = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("AlarmTrigger");
    if(AlarmTriggerString != null && FromReceiver != null && FromReceiver == true)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set flag or any value in Intent that will determine what's your purpose in that class ..

For Ex: For playing sound set a Boolean value to TRUE in Intent and send same over that class using bundle ..

Else

Set that Boolean value to FALSE if starting alarm class from some other class.